# Pass json of address to Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, json-rpc

i am wanting to import an array of json data into my contract on construct.  I want to pass it an array of address to be saved into an array in my contract.  Is this possible?  I have seen a few posts about phrasing json into a contract but could't quite extract what i am looking for.

The json data i have is structured like this; - i am wanting to extract only the HolderAddress's.

```
[
  {
    "HolderAddress": "0x00007569643bc1709561ec2e86f385df3759e5dd",
    "Balance": 100,
    "PendingBalanceUpdate": "No"
  },
  {
    "HolderAddress": "0x00089553ab5a08bfdf1dc324845a4ad7a63e26b8",
    "Balance": 9,
    "PendingBalanceUpdate": "No"
  },
  {
    "HolderAddress": "0x0017bf3bca94a016a27d496363cec4d868758bb7",
    "Balance": 650,
    "PendingBalanceUpdate": "No"
  }
]
```

Can this data be passed at the deployment of the contract and how would i link the contract to read the json file?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATM, what you can do is:

```
constructor(address[] memory addresses, uint256[] memory balances, bool[] memory flags) public {
    uint256 length = addresses.length;
    require(length == balances.length, "INVALID_INPUT");
    require(length == flags.length, "INVALID_INPUT");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // do whatever you want to do with the input data
    }
}
```

With `arr` being the array of objects in your question, you can use:

- `arr.map(x => x.HolderAddress)` as the 1st parameter
- `arr.map(x => x.Balance)` as the 2nd parameter
- `arr.map(x => x.PendingBalanceUpdate != "No")` as the 3rd parameter

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do i initially pass the json to the constructor/contract?

Comment: @Tuck: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for you time and response.  I apologies for for asking obvious and basic questions.  This is my first time playing around with json but have been learning solidity for a couple of months. 

Is this deployed from within the migration.js script? so it would look like
deployer.deploy(MyToken, arr.map(x => x.HolderAddress), arr.map(x => x.Balance)); ?

Would i also call the json array into the script or have to copy it in?

Comment: @Tuck: You're missing the last input argument (or maybe you just omitted it in order to keep the question short). As with regards to your last question, I don't understand the meaning of "call the json array into the script".

Comment: yes just keeping the reply shorter.  So i have my array of data in a json file, do i need to import/declare/not sure on the correct term that into the migrations script?  Is it best to just copy the whole thing in?

Comment: @Tuck: You can put it directly in your script, you can place it in a **JS** file and require/import that file from your script, you can put it in a JSON file and **read** that file from your script. There are many different ways. Note that this is a general JS question, which has nothing to do with Ethereum, so if you wanna dig deeper into this, then you can post it on stack overflow I suppose.

Comment: thank you i think i understand now and have enough there to do some more research.  Thank you for you time!